# runOnUiThread is not called while huge calculations

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I have got code  something like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            myClass somedata = myHugeAndVeryBusyFunction();
                    Log.d(TAG,"PING");
                    final testCallback = "progress is " + i;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.d(TAG,"PONG");
                            textview.setText(testCallback);
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                }
        }
    }).start();
```

The `Runnable` inside `runOnUiThread` is called only after full execution of the loop.
So, the runnable is called only after all calculations. Is it possible to void this disadvantage?

Comment: Do the *huge calculation* in a separate thread if it doesn't have any UI operation.

Comment: What do you mean? I have UI callback operation. I've just removed here in order to simpler reading.

Comment: @Vyacheslav : can you plese elaborate your comment in the code which says "//this runnable is call after i == 99" ??
i have doubt on the condition which you are using there..

Comment: what disadvantage are you trying to void? The code is behaving exactly how it is supposed to. Can you be more specific in what is your requirement?

Comment: I've update the question.

Comment: What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: If you add a `Thread.sleep()` in there, does the behavior change? Just wondering if the UI thread is getting starved and not processing its message queue until things quiet down.

Comment: Oh, i have found synchronized code inside the function `myHugeAndVeryBusyFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an AsyncTask to update your UI. You can periodically call onProgressUpdate from inside your myHugeAndVeryBusyFunction. That will ensure that UI is updated regularly rather than at the end. But if myHugeAndVeryBusyFunction is a big monolith, then it maybe a little hard. You will be at the mercy of the scheduler.